# Three.js - Drag and drop (XZ)

Tags: three.js, 2d

I'm new to three.js and I used the example of http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html to drag and drop my objects. The problem is that I want them to move only on the XZ plane (not on the Y axis) and I don't know how to achieve it in order to move them on a plane. The user should only be able to "slide" them on the ground. I'm using the OrbitControls instead of the TrackballControls.

https://jsfiddle.net/d58bbLey/

```
    function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

    if ( SELECTED ) {
        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject( plane );

        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
            SELECTED.position.copy( intersects[ 0 ].point.sub( offset ) );
        }
        return;
    }

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

        if ( INTERSECTED != intersects[ 0 ].object ) {

            if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
            INTERSECTED = intersects[ 0 ].object;
            INTERSECTED.currentHex = INTERSECTED.material.color.getHex();
            plane.position.copy( INTERSECTED.position );
            plane.lookAt( camera.position );
        }
        container.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    } else {
        if ( INTERSECTED ) INTERSECTED.material.color.setHex( INTERSECTED.currentHex );
        INTERSECTED = null;
        container.style.cursor = 'auto';
    }
}
```

I appreciate your help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem:
each object has a plane which lookAt the camera. So, I deleted the plane.lookAt(camera.position) and added this line:

```
plane.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( -Math.PI / 2));
```

Now my objects stays on the plane (XZ axis).

Comment: or use evencontrols http://alexan0308.github.io/threejs/examples/controls_events_example.html

Comment: Yes, that's a good possibility too ! :D
My next problem is that my collada files won't be able to move. I don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

I have to do the same stuff, so far I used the DragControls

```
const geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(5, 32, 32);
const materialSphere = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0xff0000, side: THREE.DoubleSide, wireframe: true });
const sphereMesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, materialSphere);
this.scene.add(sphereMesh);

this.dragControls = new DragControls([sphereMesh], camera, renderer.domElement);

this.dragControls.addEventListener('drag', (event) => {
  event.object.position.z = 0;
  event.object.position.x = 0;
});
```